# LinearLayout XML error Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to fix this so badly but I couldn't find where I've gone wrong.

The message:

```
Element type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Why do I get this? Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    **<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty self-explanatory error message.

You didn't close your `LinearLayout` tag. Add a `>` after `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a ">" at the end:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first LinearLayout tag isn't closed. Add a `>` to the end of it, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

                                   ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Error clearly states that you missed the closing tag. Every Layout and its attribute needs to have their own opening and closing tag. Add

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

or

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: He has both his closing tags. He's just missing the end angle bracket for the first LinearLayout.